# Doubly robust estimation of causal effects implementation

Tags: regression

Does anyone know of an implementation (other than the SAS macro) of the doubly robust estimation method found in:

> Funk, M.J., Westreich, D. et al (2011).  Doubly robust estimation of causal effects. *American Journal of Epidemiology, 173* (7): 761-767.[[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwq439)?

Comment: Is there a particular language you would *like* it in?

Comment: Implementations in any languages are welcome. I can't use the SAS macro because I don't have the SAS program.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, not sure how the typo sneaked in there

Comment: @jonsca You do a lot of editing and I have checked many of your edits when the requests come to me.  Generally you do a very nice job.  This one was very good too, just one typo sneaked in.

Answer (score 12):

Doubly robust estimation is not actually particularly hard to implement in the language of your choice. All you are actually doing is controlling for variables in two ways, rather than one- the idea being that as long as one of the two models used for control is correct, you've successfully controlled for confounding.

The easiest way to do it, in my mind, is to use Inverse-Probability-of-Treatment (IPTW) weights to weight the data set, then *also* include variables in a normal regression model. This is how the authors approach the problem in the paper linked above. There are other options as well, usually built off propensity scores used for either matching or as a covariate in the model.

There are *lots* of introductions to IPTW in whatever statistical language you prefer. I'd provide code snippets, but all of mine are in SAS, and would likely read very much like the authors.

Briefly, what you do is model the probability of *exposure* based on your covariates using something like logistic regression and estimate the predicted probability of exposure based on that model. This gives you a propensity score. The Inverse Probability of Treatment Weight is, as the name suggests, 1/Propensity Score. This sometimes produces extreme values, so some people stabilize the weight by substituting the marginal probability of exposure (obtained by a logistic regression model of the outcome and *no* covariates) for 1 in the equation above.

Instead of treating each subject in your analysis as 1 subject, you now treat them as n copies of a subject, where n is their weight. If you run your regression model using those weights *and* including covariates, out comes a doubly robust estimate.

A word of caution however: While doubly (or triply, etc.) robust estimation gives you *more* chances to specify the correct covariate model, it does not guarantee you will do so. And more importantly, cannot save you from unmeasured confounding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a free/trial version of SAS?

Comment: @ADB Hopefully someone will come along with an implementation in R - I'd do it, but I've got some urgent deadlines coming up. If you're in a place where you have access to statisticians or just folks who like coding, this should be *very* straightforward to implement in whatever package you have. On the scale of "I'll buy you lunch" in terms of the appropriate bribe :)

Comment: @ADB This [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/vignettes/twang.pdf) for the [twang](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/index.html) package in R has a nice overview of propensity score analysis and doubly robust estimators.

Comment: @Fomite I think you meant "...some people stabilize the weight by substituting the marginal probability of exposure (obtained by a logistic regression model of the **treatment** and no covariates) for 1 in the equation above."

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there was an implementation in Stata even before the article you cited was published: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0149.

Answer (score 2):

The [tmle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmle/index.html) R package implemented the Targeted Minimum Loss Based Estimator, which is double robust and efficient under conditions. It has the additional advantage that it is a substitution estimator, as opposed to the Augmented IPTW (which is the one I assume you are referring to).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @IvanDiaz. It might help if you stated what language the `tmle` package is for, perhaps a link to more info, & where to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the estimator described in Funk et al. 2011 (augmented inverse probability weights), implemented in the `zEpid` Python 3 library within the `AIPTW` class. Details and syntax are [HERE](https://zepid.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Reference/generated/zepid.causal.doublyrobust.AIPW.AIPTW.html#zepid.causal.doublyrobust.AIPW.AIPTW). The library also includes TMLE, in case you wanted to use both approaches

Answer (score 0):

There is an R package which implements this DR estimator of the ATE (as well as some other things), the `npcausal` package: https://github.com/ehkennedy/npcausal

The function that fits a DR estimator is `ate()`